# SAML 2.0 & Okta C#

Tags: saml, okta

I'm working with a web app which calling IDP (Okta) and should receive a response to another page as SAML assertion.

How do I "catch"  the post SAML Assertion and process it in a landing page/web app?

Thanks
Shnetz

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at libraries like:

https://www.componentsource.com/product/componentspace-saml2-component
or
https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices

which will help you SAML enable your app.  They will take care of handling the SAML logic as a service provider for your app.